# Clone, append and remove

Tags: jquery, append, clone

I have a couple of items as such

```
<div class="item">
  <figure>
    <span class="overlay"></span>
    <img...>
    <figcaption>
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

I am trying to clone `figcaption h3` so that when the item is clicked the `figcaption h3` is appended to `overlay` and when another item is clicked the title of the previous item is removed and the title of the next clicked cloned and appended... Sure I could avoid using jQuery but there are academic reasons for solving problems!

My crude attempt is as follows

```
$(".item").on("click", function() { 
  $(".overlay h3").remove();    
  var $title = $('.overlay');
      $('figcaption h3').each(function(i) {
      $(this).clone().appendTo($title.eq(i));
  });   
});
```

The problem is, every `h3` title is appended to its `overlay` when any item is clicked. Also the appended clone is not removed totally. The title is re-cloned every time and there is always one cloned left. Is cloning the title even the best method or maybe using `html()`?

Comment: Your html does not contain the `meta-overlay` tag? I think you mean `overlay` in your jquery script.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it's a typo. I will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
$(".item").on("click", function() { 
  $(".overlay h3").remove();    

  $h3 = $(this).find('h3').clone();

  $(this).find('.overlay').html($h3);
});
```

This grabs only the H3 of the clicked element and appends it to the span.